# Text box overflows when adding a custom flagging reason

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, design, comment-flags

When flagging a comment (I was in the review queue when I did) the text box is wider than the gray area. I'm on Chrome, Version 65.0.3325.181 (Official Build) (64-bit).

[image: text box too wide]

Comment: This **does** affect other sites, so it's not *only* code review.

Comment: This affects Edge, so I'm assuming it affects other browsers as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

balpha just built out a fix for this as part of the responsive design changes.

[image: image of "in need of moderator intervention" textarea with proper width]